# Важная тема: Коты/коты или собаки

Tags: заглавная

Можете, пожалуйста, сказать, если мы в русском языке после двоеточия в заголовках пишем первое слово с заглавной буквы или нет?

Какой вариант этого заголовка, мною написанного, правильный:

1. Важная тема: Коты или собаки;
2. Важная тема: коты или собаки.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно:
Важная тема: коты или собаки.[Д.Э. Розенталь.Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация. П.2.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168#pp168)